# Legend state persistence plugin is not setting on local

Tags: local-storage, state, persistence

I am trying to working with `legend state` persistence plugin in local. I do all the setups and imports are ok.
But `localstorage` value is not setting. And `indexDB`'s database name `legend` and table `store' are setting fine. But table entries are not.
Here is my code:

```
import {
  configureObservablePersistence,
  persistObservable,
} from "@legendapp/state/persist";
import { observable, when } from "@legendapp/state";
import { ObservablePersistIndexedDB } from "@legendapp/state/persist-plugins/indexeddb";
import { ObservablePersistLocalStorage } from "@legendapp/state/persist-plugins/local-storage";

// Automatically persist state
configureObservablePersistence({
  persistLocal: ObservablePersistIndexedDB,
  persistLocalOptions: {
    indexedDB: {
      databaseName: "Legend",
      version: 1,
      tableNames: ["store"],
    },
  },
});

const state$ = observable({
  firstName: "Golam",
  lastName: "Mostafa",
});

persistObservable(state$, {
  persistLocal: ObservablePersistIndexedDB,
  local: {
    name: "store",
    indexedDB: {
      itemID: "store-1",
    },
  },
});

persistObservable(state$, {
  persistLocal: ObservablePersistLocalStorage,
  local: "state",
});
```

I am expecting that the `localstorage` will be set with `state` as key and `{ firstName: "Golam", lastName: "Mostafa", }` as value as well as table entry for `indexDB`.

I need to know, where I'm doing wrong? TIA.
Here is the docs: [Legend state persistence](https://legendapp.com/open-source/state/persistence/)
Here is my code: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/golammostafa13/explore-legend/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400072v6fk0hbcypt%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400032v6fb1ei4ag0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400052v6fbutp1zup%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400062v6fjisv5d2v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clmvtjr2400032v6fb1ei4ag0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400032v6fb1ei4ag0%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmw530fz01kp2v6flvtdf332%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400022v6f3iq39xh6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252FShowModal.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtk1j5006d2v6faybnir1z%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fpage.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmw5234o01ar2v6fjnjdvao2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252FTodoList.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmw530fz01kp2v6flvtdf332%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmw5l71b02n52v6f05i1p5lf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmvtjr2400062v6fjisv5d2v%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400062v6fjisv5d2v%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmvtk6xe007g2v6foq7eyvci%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtk6xe007g2v6foq7eyvci%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmvtjr2400052v6fbutp1zup%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400052v6fbutp1zup%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400042v6fsk0s462i%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400042v6fsk0s462i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clmvtjrbs0010e5ea31gd16x1%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtk1gk005g2v6fclhu5wso%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: I got it. Thanks to @jmeistrich. 
Answer link: [answer link](https://www.reddit.com/r/expo/comments/13fwe75/comment/k1wka9w/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)